How to reuse a repository for each request
I am trying to use dependency injection for a repository, which in Program.cs is registered as a service. However the repository keeps getting reinstanciated each time the controller is called.
I have a feeling i need to move this to something not in the controller, and/or actually use the IServiceProvider rarther than just declaring it. This would give it has some form of permanence, but i am not sure what/where/how to do this.
The repo is just a List<Book> with CRUD operations and does not sit over entity framework or another data framework/database. Mostly as im just trying to learn and get an example of a repo over a list with DI in MVC. Its entirely possible that im flogging a dead horse with my approach.
I dont get any errors when navigating through my pages. When i break through the code, the operations within the repo are called fine, and do what i expect them to do. Its just when i go to my page of "view all" or "add" the repo is reset because of its reinstanciation (i presume).
Other than whats below, program.cs has not been changed.
Program.Cs
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IBookRepository, BookRepository>();

var app = builder.Build();

BookRepository.cs
    public class BookRepository : IBookRepository
    {
        private List<Book> _books;

        public BookRepository()
        {
            _books = new List<Book>();
        }

        public List<Book> GetAllBooks()
        {
            return _books;
        }

        public Book GetBookByISBN(string ISBN)
        {
            Book book = _books.Find(x => x.ISBN == ISBN);
            return book;
        }

        public void CreateBook(Book book) 
        {
            _books.Add(book);
        }

        public void DeleteBook(Book book)
        {
            _books.Remove(book);
        }
    }

and the LibraryController.cs constructor
        public LibraryController(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            if (serviceProvider == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(serviceProvider));
            }

            _bookRepository = serviceProvider.GetService<IBookRepository>() ??
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(_bookRepository));
        }


In ASP.Net, a service scope correlates with a HTTP request, so there will be a single instance of each repository per-HTTP request. If you're using a list as the persistence, then you probably want to register each of these as a singleton, rather than scoped.

@JohnathanBarclay is spot on. To ensure that the state of your repository is persisted between requests, you will have to register it as singleton, thus using builder.Services.AddSingleton<IBookRepository, BookRepository>(); Note that this will work only for your current test repository, and will unlikely be a good solution when moving to an Entity-Framework-based implementation.

I recommend reading up on the service lifetimes offered by MS's dependency injection container.

Also prevent injecting and using the IServiceProvider in application code. Instead of injecting IServiceProvider into LibraryController, make IBookRepository the parameter of the constructor.

@JohnathanBarclay smashed it mate, thank you. That was it.

If you ever need more complex object creation or detainment, you can have your own singleton factory wired with DI, and this  factory can get you what you need. .AddScoped<IRepositoryFactory, RepositoryFactory>(); in Controller _repositoryFactory.GetBookRepository

"Repositories" tend to be singletons (i.e. statics). Seems pointless to "inject them". Or keep "re-creating" them.
